# Mounting ssd. Expectations vs reality about server load

Tags: mysql, web-server, hard-drive, hardware, ssd

I'v installed SSD on my server and moved tmp folder, mysql data folder and 2 most loaded websites(php) on it.

I'v expected that server load will fall a little bit, but it seems that it is on the same level as it was.

So the question is, should the server load decreased with ssd installation or installing an ssd is not a powerful mean  to decrease load?

**UPDATE 1**

The system if Fedora.
In general I struggle of CPU load, which is made mostly by MySQL.

My proposal is that mysql uses a lot of io ops, but might be I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by server load? Which operating system are you using ?

Comment: To solve the problem correctly, you must first identify the problem correctly. It sounds like you misidentified the cause of the problem. What is the server doing? What "load" are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

If the server's performance is bounded by disk read time or load, adding an SSD will certainly help.  If it is bound by RAM, disk writes, network, or CPU load, an SSD will not help.

You should consider using `top`, `iotop`, and `bwmon` to see the data on this.  `top` will show you memory usage and CPU usage, and is especially good for seeing what is going on in cases like this (though the results can be somewhat misleading on SMP systems).  For instance, if all your CPU usage is going to `hi`, or hardware interrupts, the issue is likely disk (or sometimes network) related.

If this is windows, ignore that and use `resmon.exe` to check load.

This is a very broad topic, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction.